# Getting updating entries error while trying to add items to database

Tags: c#, sql, database, visual-studio, entity

I'm trying to add items to my database by using my "Add" button but whenever I try to add compiler says "An error occured while updating the entries. See the inner exception details."

This is my add button code :

```
private void button_Ekle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                tblKullanici kln = new tblKullanici();
                kln.KullaniciAdi = textBox_Adi.Text;
                kln.KullaniciSoyadi = textBox_Soyadi.Text;
                kln.Email = textBox_Email.Text;
                kln.Tarih = date_DogumTarihi.Value;
                kln.Durum = true;
                kln.Telefon = textBox_Telefon.Text;
                db.tblKullanici.Add(kln);
                db.SaveChanges();
                UyeleriListele();
            }
            catch (Exception hata)
            {

                label_Message.Text = "UyeEkle-Ekle-" + hata.InnerException.Message.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: And what is the inner exception?

Comment: I can't see the inner exception idk why

Answer (score 0):

I just updated my entity model from my database and it's fixed! It was because of my Id column - the "is Identity" was "No" when I change it to yes my problem has been solved.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.